# Excel VBA ERROR - Function or Interface marked as restricted. or the function uses an Automation type not supported in Visual Basic

Tags: excel, compiler-errors, vba

I am writing a small score lookup program in VBA and the following code gives the error in the title, i'm new to VBA and the error points to the first line which was generated by Excel itself.

```
Private Sub btnSearch_Click()
    Name = txtSearch.Text
    AmountOfEntries = Range("i10")
    For i = 1 To AmountOfEntries
        If Range("a" + i) = Name Then
            cell = i
        Else
            cell = "Error"
        End If
    Next i

    If cell = "Error" Then
        lblScore.Caption = "Your Username is Incorrect. Please Try Again"
    Else
        lblScore.Caption = "Your Score Is : " + Range("b" + cell)
    End If
End Sub
```

My spreadsheet contains a list of names in the 'A' column then a list of scores in the 'B' column. in 'I10' there is a field containing the amount of entries in the list.

Comment: what is the error number and description? Do you have `Option Explicit` instruction at the top of the module?

Comment: Where is `cell` declared and what is it declared as?

Answer (score 0):

You should try to avoid using "name", "cell" etc (generic terms in VBA) as variable names. Try defining your variables `Dim strName as String, i as Integer, intCell as Integer, intAmountOfEntries as Integer`.

Also, your range statements should be changed to use `&` and to specify that you want to use the VALUE not the RANGE aspect of the object:

`Range("a" & i).Value` and `Range("b" & intCell).Value`

EDIT =============

Re your comments below:

I think the issue is due to you using cell as an integer (the row number) and also a string ("error"). I would create a new variable to detect if there is an error or not:

`Dim blnError as Boolean`

Then replace this:

`cell = "Error"` with `blnError = True`

Your If statement below will need to be amended to `If blnError = True Then`

Can you confirm that you have a Sheet called "Sheet1"? If not, then that is why the `Sheets("Sheet1")` code doesn't work. I normally use the VBA names for sheets instead - in the VBE you can see what they are in the project explorer (name before the brackets) and you can change them using the properties window. Then you just use `sheetname.Range("A1")`.

Comment: Thanks, i used 'Dim' and also '.Value' But am now getting the error   Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: Also if i use 'Sheets("Sheet1")' before range it says the error 'Application defined or object defined error